# How can we disable mouse Pointstick in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, mouse, trackpoint

I want to disable my mouse PointStick. In Windows 10, I did that by disabling PointStick from "Dell Pointing Devices Software" provided in Windows 10 in System Tray.

[image]

Can I do something like this in Ubuntu 18.04? Please help me in repeating the same thing for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
xinput list
```

It will give you a list of devices, look after your device name under "Virtual core pointer", for example mine is:

```
"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
```

Then run:

```
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Enabled" 0
```

Replace "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" with your device name.

Don't forget that this is only temporary, to make it permanent you can put the command somewhere which gets automatically executed, for example in `~/.profile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and accurate response. It worked.... Thanks once again..

Comment: @Programmer-X you're welcome ;)